# How to find IP address of Azure API App to generate a SAS token for it?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-api-apps

I have deployed a piece of code in Azure API App which reads the data from Azure Table Storage. I want to restrict it to the read access by putting the IP address of the Azure API app server. How to find the IP address of Azure API app?

Comment: As Gaurav said it might not help you but you can find the outbound IP addresses through portal https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/02/01/how-do-i-determine-the-outbound-ip-addresses-of-my-azure-app-service/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you are able to find the IP address of Azure API app, it will not work as IP ACLing will only work for IP addresses outside of Azure. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1) (section `Parameters common to account SAS and service SAS tokens`)

> IP. An optional parameter that specifies **an IP address or a range of
>   IP addresses *outside of Azure*** (see the section Routing session
>   configuration state for Express Route) from which to accept requests.